# Reassign values on reattaching script

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a custom node with some export variables but when I remove the script and then reattach it the export variable values get lost,

so I used `get_meta()` to reassign the values like this:

```
tool
extends Node2D

export(int) var value=0 setget set_value

func set_value(new_val=null,initial=false):
    print("Invoked set_value")
    if(initial and self.has_meta("data")):
        value=self.get_meta("data")
        return
    
    value=new_val
    self.set_meta("data",value)

func _init():
    set_value(null,true)
```

but there are 2 problems:

1. I have to write every setget function inside `_init()`
2. When I make changes to the script and save it the setget functions get invoked twice

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
export var value:int = get_meta("value", 0) setget set_value
func set_value(new_val:int) -> void:
    value = new_val
    set_meta("value", value)
```

When the script is loaded it should execute the initialization which takes the value from metadata (or a default value if the metadata is not set). Godot, nor the core, will call the setter. Since the setter always sets the metadata, the value should not be lost.

When the script is modified Godot will set all the properties, which results in Godot calling all the setters (each setter will run only once). In this case Godot is setting the same value it had, so the value should not be lost.

This approach does not require `_init`.